# Problem regarding getting split data of JSON - Another issue

Tags: arduino-uno, json, serial-data

In my recent project, I'm working with Arduino and JSON. I've successfully split the JSON data I want. My JSON data length is fixed. So, I used the `length()` function and I'm getting the length of my data.

Now, my input JSON data is:

```
{"TPS":"0.40","MAP":"0.95","LOAD":"14"}
```

Using the `length()` function, its length is `39`.

But when I use an `if` statement like `if(len == 39)` and put my logic inside this, I'm not getting the split data. Below is my whole code.

Here, I'm displaying my data on LCD.

```
#include<LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 7, 6, 5, 4);
String data_TPS_Json = "";
String data_MAP_Json = "";
String data_LOAD_TM_Json = "";
String response = "";
bool begin = false;
int counter = 0;
int len = 0;
char in;
float TPS_Json;
float MAP_Json;
float LOAD_TM_Json;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop() {
  while(Serial.available() || !begin) {
    in = Serial.read();
    if (in == '{') {
      begin = true;
    }
    if(begin) {
      counter++;
      response += (in);
      len = response.length();
      if(len == 39) {
        if(counter >= 9 && counter <= 12) {
          data_TPS_Json += (in);
        }
        if(counter >= 22 && counter <= 25) {
          data_MAP_Json += (in);
        }
        if(counter >= 36 && counter <= 37) {
          data_LOAD_TM_Json += (in);
        }   
      }
    }

    if(in == '}') {
      break;
    }
    delay(1);
  }
  TPS_Json = data_TPS_Json.toFloat();
  MAP_Json = data_MAP_Json.toFloat();
  LOAD_TM_Json = data_LOAD_TM_Json.toFloat();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(TPS_Json);
  lcd.setCursor(8, 0);
  lcd.print(MAP_Json);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(LOAD_TM_Json);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution. Using `substring()` function, I can able to split my data.

Here, suppose I have two input data with fixed length.

```
{"TPS":"0.40","MAP":"0.95","LOAD":"14"}

{"LOAD":"2.40","RPM":"4200","INJECTION_TIME":"4.87"}
```

So, using `length()` function I got the length of both data. So, I can able to differentiate the different data. In my previous code, I use counter and according to counter index I split my data. But somehow it does not work. So, after using `substring()` function I got the same result even better.

And below is my whole arduino code:

```
#include<LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 7, 6, 5, 4);

String data_TPS_Json = "";
String data_MAP_Json = "";
String data_LOAD_TM_Json = "";

String data_LOAD_RI_Json = "";
String data_RPM_Json = "";
String data_INJECTION_TIME_Json = "";

String response = "";
bool begin = false;

char in;
int len = 0;

float TPS_Json;
float MAP_Json;
float LOAD_TM_Json;

float LOAD_RI_Json;
float RPM_Json;
float INJECTION_TIME_Json;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop()
{
  while(Serial.available() || !begin)
  {
      in = Serial.read();

      if (in == '{')
      {
        begin = true;
      }

      if(begin)
      {
        response += (in);
      }

      if(in == '}')
      {
        break;
      }

      delay(1);
  }

  len = response.length();

  if(len == 39)
  {
    data_TPS_Json = response.substring(8, 12);
    data_MAP_Json = response.substring(21, 25);
    data_LOAD_TM_Json = response.substring(35, 37);

    jsonMapTps();
  }

  if(len == 52)
  {
    data_LOAD_RI_Json = response.substring(9, 13);
    data_RPM_Json = response.substring(22, 26);
    data_INJECTION_TIME_Json = response.substring(46, 50);

    jsonRpmLoad();
  }
}

void jsonMapTps()
{
    TPS_Json = data_TPS_Json.toFloat();
    MAP_Json = data_MAP_Json.toFloat();
    LOAD_TM_Json = data_LOAD_TM_Json.toFloat();

    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print(TPS_Json);
    lcd.setCursor(8, 0);
    lcd.print(MAP_Json);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(LOAD_TM_Json);  
}

void jsonRpmLoad()
{
    LOAD_RI_Json = data_LOAD_RI_Json.toFloat();
    RPM_Json = data_RPM_Json.toFloat();
    INJECTION_TIME_Json = data_INJECTION_TIME_Json.toFloat();

    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print(LOAD_RI_Json);
    lcd.setCursor(8, 0);
    lcd.print(RPM_Json);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(INJECTION_TIME_Json);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your loop handles the situation where the data comes in too slowly. Looking at your `while` condition:

```
while(Serial.available() || !begin)
```

Once you receive the start char, this becomes:

```
while(Serial.available())
```

Now, if there is a delay in the serial buffer, the loop exits before you have the entire message.

You should change the loop so it only ends when you have all 39 chars.

```
void loop() {
    while (39 != response.length()) {  // Keep going until full msg {
        // Check for data in serial buffer
        if (Serial.available()) {
            in = Serial.read();
            .....
        }
        // No data?
        else {
            delay(10);
        }
    }

    TPS_Json = data_TPS_Json.toFloat();
    MAP_Json = data_MAP_Json.toFloat();
    .....
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I tried it out. But still not getting data. This looks logically correct, but If data length changed then what? By the way, I got the solution.